# how to access LPD data from the OS

Tags: linux, monitoring, ibm

We have several IBM System x servers, each of which has a "Light Path Diagnostic" (LPD) panel of LEDs.  I want to be able to monitor the status of the LPD alerts from Nagios, but can't find where they are exposed to the OS.

How can I read the LPD status from the (Linux) OS on an IBM System x server?

Answer (score 0):

Management controllers, which control those LEDs, are usually IPMI-compliant.  So you would need the OpenIPMI package for Linux and IPMI plugin for Nagios.  Configuration may be somewhat server-specific (there are several generations of management chips - BMC, IMM, RSA2, to name a few).  Very old (10 years or so) servers may need ibmasm package instead of OpenIPMI.

Comment: I've used IPMI/OpenIPMI, but haven't found the status of those LEDs in any of the data I've queried out of it so far.  Usually the event that triggered the light to turn on can be found in the SEL; but I can't find a simple boolean for "is the light on?"